# problem with use Mvvm and Retrofit and Rxjava live data in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, observable, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm new in kotlin and I'm trying to use retrofit with Rxjava and live data in MVVM architecture.
I config retrofit, and also use observable and subscribe in ViewModel to make observable variable to use in activity binding layout.
I have a button in my view and when I click on it, the request method gets to start and subscription write a log of its own data. but my variable gets null at first and after seconds, when retrofit completed its task, my variable gets data but log value doesn't update.

this is my retrofit initialize class

```
class ApiService {

private val INSTANCE =
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.janbarar.ir/App/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(IRetrofitMethods::class.java)


private fun <T> callBack(iDataTransfer: IDataTransfer<T>) =

    object : Callback<T> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {

            val data = response.body()
            if (data != null)
                iDataTransfer.onSuccess(data)
            else
                try {
                    throw Exception("data is empty")
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    iDataTransfer.onError(ex)
                }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
            iDataTransfer.onError(t)
        }
    }

fun getCategories(iDataTransfer: IDataTransfer<List<Category>>) =
        INSTANCE.getCategories().enqueue(callBack(iDataTransfer))
```

this is an interface for retrofit

```
@GET("GetCategories")
fun getCategories(): Call<List<Category>>
```

this is my model class. I think the problem is here. because the observable send null data before retrofit finish its work.

```
fun getCategories(): Observable<ArrayList<Category>> {

        val result = arrayListOf<Category>()

        api.getCategories(object : IDataTransfer<List<Category>> {

            override fun onSuccess(data: List<Category>) {

                result.addAll(data)
            }

            override fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Model", throwable.message!!)
            }
        })

        return Observable.just(result)
    }
```

and this is also my ViewModel class

```
class ProductViewModel(private val model: ProductModel) : ViewModel() {

    var isLoading = ObservableField(false)
    var categoryList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Category>>()
    private var compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    fun getCategories() {

        isLoading.set(true)
        compositeDisposable +=
            model.getCategories()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({

                    categoryList.value = it

                }, {

                    Log.e("ViewModel", it.message.toString())
                })
        isLoading.set(false)
    }
```

finally, it's my activity

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
 private val vm: ProductViewModel by viewModel()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.vm = vm

        vm.categoryList.observe(this, Observer {

            if (it != null)
                Log.e("activity", it.toString())
        })   
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to add `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())` to Retrofit so it gives you an `Single` / `Observable` straight away without you having to do the conversion manually like you're doing

Answer (score 1):

As ExpensiveBelly mentioned in a comment, Retrofit provides a call adapter for RxJava, so you can let your API return `Observable<List<Category>>` directly.  To do this, you will need to add the RxJava call adapter dependency to your app module's `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:(version)'
```

Add the call adapter factory when constructing your `Retrofit` instance:

```
private val INSTANCE =
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.janbarar.ir/App/")
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()) // add this
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(IRetrofitMethods::class.java)
```

And then just let your service return an Observable directly:

```
@GET("GetCategories")
fun getCategories(): Observable<List<Category>>
```

If `ApiService` needs to do some handling before the rest of the app gets the response, you can use RxJava operators like `map`.

---

It would be illustrative to see why your code doesn't work and how to fix it.  When you call `api.getCategories(someCallback)`, one of your callback methods will be called at some point in the future.  In the meantime, the `model.getCategories()` method will return immediately.

When you subscribe to the returned `Observable`, it emits the `result` variable, which is currently an empty list.  `result` will eventually have some data in it, but your code will not be informed of this at all.

What you really want to do is emit the list of categories when it becomes available.  The standard way to get an `Observable` from a callback API is with `Observable.create`:

```
fun getCategories(): Observable<ArrayList<Category>> {

    return Observable.create { emitter -> 

        api.getCategories(object : IDataTransfer<List<Category>> {

            override fun onSuccess(data: List<Category>) {

                emitter.onNext(data)
                emitter.onComplete()
            }

            override fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {
                emitter.onError(throwable)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Of course, it's better to just use `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` if possible, since this work has already been done there.

Comment: If they were to use `call.execute()` instead of `call.enqueue`, then they could just use `Observable.fromCallable` instead of having to use `Observable.create()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I tried both methods and came up with the answer.